# Not getting my data to show up in cord_flip type graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

histograms, box plots, and other plots are showing up, but I want to represent two variables on one, and any time I try to do that it throws an error. My data is subset into a dataframe where the variable I am working with is only equal to 0 or 1, there are no nan's or other weird frequencies (I have checked). Below is the code I am using and here is what I am trying to show. The variable "FREQ_DAY_ALL" is a categorical variable with 5 factors, and I am trying to represent the *n* of ever reporting suicidality.

```
Test<-PAST_YR_SUI_CANN %>% 
            group_by(MH_SUI_EVR)%>%
            mutate(MH_SUI_EVR_Count=n())%>%
            ggplot(aes(x=factor(FREQ_CANN_USE), y=MH_SUI_EVR_Count,fill=MH_SUI_EVR))+
geom_bar(data = subset(PAST_YR_SUI_CANN, MH_SUI_EVR==0), stat = "identity") +

geom_bar(data = subset(PAST_YR_SUI_CANN, MH_SUI_EVR==1), stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip() +
theme_minimal() 

Test
```

I have tried it both in an out of quotations for my 0 & 1's, but it gives me the error of "caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (485)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x`"

This particular code says it isnt working due to not being able to find "MH_SUI_EVR_COUNT".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you can't access the column you created with `mutate()` in the `geom_bar(subset(PAST_YR_SUI_CANN))`, because you are are specifying the 'unmutated' `PAST_YR_SUI_CANN`, not the mutated `PAST_YR_SUI_CANN` (that has the extra column).

Some potential solutions are to perform the mutate and plotting in two steps, to filter `MH_SUI_EVR` before plotting so you don't have to subset it in `geom_bar()`, or to use curly braces to access the mutated `PAST_YR_SUI_CANN`.

For example, using the built-in 'iris' dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# perform the filtering and plotting in two steps
iris_with_species_count <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)%>%
  mutate(Species_count=n())

ggplot(iris_with_species_count, 
       aes(x=factor(Species), y=Species_count, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(data = subset(iris_with_species_count,
                         Species=="setosa"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(iris_with_species_count,
                         Species=="virginica"), stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# filter the Species before you plot
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)%>%
  mutate(Species_count=n())%>%
  filter(Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Species), y=Species_count, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# use curly braces to pass 'iris' with the mutated column to geom_bar
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species)%>%
  mutate(Species_count=n())%>%
  {ggplot(data = ., aes(x=factor(Species), y=Species_count, fill=Species))+
  geom_bar(data = subset(., Species=="setosa"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_bar(data = subset(., Species=="virginica"), stat = "identity")+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal()}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>